# Count total record and insert into another table field

Tags: mysql

How can i count total record from table1 and insert result into table2 field3 which already created.

```
Insert into table2 (filed3)
Select count (id) from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the space

```
Insert into table2 (filed3)
Select count(id) from table1
            ^----------------------------here
```

Comment: An error found #1364. Field 'city' doesn't have a default value. How to fix it

Comment: No idea since I don't know your query. Try to research for yourself and if you don't find a solution then you can ask another question on StackOverflow